# Creating a custom shape for Slider Thumb in Flutter (Slider and RangeSlider)

Tags: flutter, dart, slider, rangeslider

I'm currently working on a Flutter project and I need assistance with creating a custom shape for the Slider Thumb. I have both a regular Slider and a RangeSlider in my app, and I would like to customize the appearance of the thumb for both of them.
To provide a clear understanding of the issue, I have attached screenshots of both sliders:
[image: Slider widget] [image: Range slider widget]

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or code samples on how to create a custom shape for the Slider Thumb in Flutter. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom thumb shape by extending SliderComponentShape and use this in your Slider:

```
class AppSliderShape extends SliderComponentShape {
    final double thumbRadius;

    const AppSliderShape({required this.thumbRadius});

    @override
    Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
        return Size.fromRadius(thumbRadius);
    }

    @override
    void paint(
      PaintingContext context,
      Offset center, {
      required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = Colors.white;

    // draw icon with text painter
    const iconData = Icons.drag_handle;
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl);
    textPainter.text = TextSpan(
        text: String.fromCharCode(iconData.codePoint),
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: thumbRadius * 2,
          fontFamily: iconData.fontFamily,
          color: sliderTheme.thumbColor,
        ));
    textPainter.layout();

    final Offset textCenter = Offset(center.dx - (textPainter.width / 2),
        center.dy - (textPainter.height / 2));
    const cornerRadius = 4.0;

    // draw the background shape here..
    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectXY(
          Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 30, height: 20), cornerRadius, cornerRadius),
      paint,
    );

    textPainter.paint(canvas, textCenter);
  }
}
```

Then in your SliderTheme:

```
SliderTheme(
data: SliderThemeData(
    thumbColor: Colors.teal,
    thumbShape: AppSliderShape(thumbRadius: 10),
    ),
child: Slider(),
),
```

[image: Slider with custom shape]

Answer (score 0):

You may give a try this

```
SliderTheme(
data: SliderThemeData(
        thumbColor: Colors.green,
        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20)),
child: Slider(
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (val) {
        _value = val;
        setState(() {});
      },
    ),
  ),
```